# working on a project using altera DE2-115, the project involves showing output on a screen

Tags: verilog, vga, intel-fpga

working on a project using altera DE2-115, the project involves showing output on a screen, i'm having hard time using VGA with verilog, could you please show or link me to a very simple working example so that i could understand the concept and apply it on my project

Comment: I don't think you'll get VGA output with 'a very simple working example', it's not a trivial task. You'll have to learn the interface, how it works with frame timing, etc. If you have a specific question you might get help, but I don't think you'll get a generic step by step tutorial written for you here. What specifically are you having a hard time with?

Answer (score 1):

[FPGA4FUN](http://www.fpga4fun.com/) has some VGA examples [making a pong game](http://www.fpga4fun.com/PongGame.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have system-cd of de2-115 board. In its demonstration have vga controller and you can use demonstration to know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried examples or "system builder" Terasic provides with board?
http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=139&No=502&PartNo=4